# Dynamically changing RangeValidator properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

How can I hard code my RangeValidator1 on button click to perform differently depending on the specific type of product being viewed, for example:

```
if(id == 1)
{
RangeValidator1.Enabled = true;
RangeValidator1.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = "6";
RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = "1";
RangeValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Only 6 allowed per customer";
}
else if(id == 2)
{
RangeValidator1.Enabled = true;
RangeValidator1.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = "10";
RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = "1";
RangeValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Only 10 allowed per customer";
}
else
RangeValidator.Enabled = false;
```

That is the general gist of what I want to achieve upon button click, but it is throwing an error about The value " of the MaximumValue property RangeValidator1 cannot be converted to type Integer.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

RangeValidator1.MaximumValue requires a string value like you

```
RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = "10";
```

to make it get from integer variable ,add .ToString() to this variable like this

```
    int x = 10;
    RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = x.ToString();
```